# Scrollviewer in UWP app not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollview, win-universal-app

I have a page in landscape mode, set in code with the next line:

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped | DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```

Following is code for full screen mode:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

In my scrollviewer, I want to include some dynamically created charts from `syncfusion` package.
 I thought this was the problem but after a while, I tried creating some rows in a grid with just textblocks so I could try the scrollviewer and it doesn't work either.

This is all my page content (except page and page.resources content) :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource AccentBrush}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <TextBlock Name="Statistic_name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="23" Text="Estadísticas"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,15,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Name="Combo_device" PlaceholderText="Contenedor" SelectionChanged="Combo_device_SelectionChanged" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Combo_sensor" PlaceholderText="Sensor" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Name="Combo_number" PlaceholderText="Número" />
            <!-- SelectionChanged="Combo_number_SelectionChanged" -->
            <Button Name="Show_data" Grid.Column="3" Click="Show_data_Button_Click" Content="Cargar Datos"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <ScrollViewer  Margin="20,20,20,20" Name="Scroll_container" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <Grid Name="Stack_panel_scroll_statistics">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Hola 0</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Hola 1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Hola 2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3">Hola 3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4">Hola 4</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5">Hola 5</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6">Hola 6</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7">Hola 7</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="8">Hola 8</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="9">Hola 9</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="10">Hola 10</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="11">Hola 11</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="12">Hola 12</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="13">Hola 13</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="14">Hola 14</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="15">Hola 15</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="16">Hola 16</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="17">Hola 17</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Can somebody tell me where the error is?**

I tried by modifying the code a lot and the result is always the same. I thought it was because the content was dynamically created in `C#` part but after trying with textblocks, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: your StackPanels are obsolete

Comment: can u try settinga a maxheight  <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="650"

Comment: @SeeSharp what should I use instead? I am new in UWP and WP.

Comment: well u use stack panels to stack items (no kidding :D), but in your case they have only one direct child

for example 
`<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,15,0"> <Grid>`

is exactly the same as 
`<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,15,0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the  `<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>` for `Grid.Row=2` which encloses your scrollViewer to `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` or specify a minimum height for your scrollviewer.
**EDIT**
Remove Stackpanel also and just simply use a Scrollviewer

Working Code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock Name="Statistic_name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="23" Text="Estadísticas"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,15,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Name="Combo_device" PlaceholderText="Contenedor" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Combo_sensor" PlaceholderText="Sensor" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Name="Combo_number" PlaceholderText="Número" />
                <!-- SelectionChanged="Combo_number_SelectionChanged" -->
                <Button Name="Show_data" Grid.Column="3"  Content="Cargar Datos"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Margin="20,20,20,20" Name="Scroll_container" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                <Grid Name="Stack_panel_scroll_statistics">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Hola 0</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Hola 1</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Hola 2</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3">Hola 3</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4">Hola 4</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5">Hola 5</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6">Hola 6</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7">Hola 7</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="8">Hola 8</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="9">Hola 9</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="10">Hola 10</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="11">Hola 11</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="12">Hola 12</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="13">Hola 13</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="14">Hola 14</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="15">Hola 15</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="16">Hola 16</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="17">Hola 17</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: I tried and doesn't work neither. I just see just from "Hola 0" to "Hola 6" and a bit of "Hola 7" but scroll doesn't work

Comment: I will mark your asnwer as valid because your demo works but I have problems when I replace the textblocks by the 2 or 3 dynamically generated charts. I just see part of the first chart and the scroll doesn't work. I will try to solve it and in case I get it to work, I will update my question to show a way of doing it. Thank you for your time man!

Comment: Np bro. If you are just seeing part the just check if there's any minheight or width defined or if the enclosing parent has some height or width defined, which might be the one ccausing problem. Scroll will work if the content height is more than scroll height.